# How to remove Parent checkbox in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I have created one Treestore in pygtk. Everything is fine only problem is, I don't want patent checkbox. you can see in below picture.

```
Computer1 [ ]-----This checkbox I don't want
    C drive [ ]
    D drive [ ]
    E drive [ ]
```

I have written code as,

```
self.view = gtk.TreeView( model )
self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.renderer.set_property( 'editable', False )

self.renderer1 = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
self.renderer1.set_property('activatable', True)
self.renderer1.connect( 'toggled', self.col1_toggled_cb, model )

self.column0 = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Computer Name", self.renderer, text=0)

self.column1 = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Select Drive", self.renderer1 )
self.column1.add_attribute( self.renderer1, "active", 1)
self.view.append_column( self.column0 )
self.view.append_column( self.column1 )

self.tree_store = gtk.TreeStore( gobject.TYPE_STRING,
                                 gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN )
for item in tasks.keys():
    parent = self.tree_store.append( None, (item, None) )
    if len(tasks[item])>1:
        for x in range(0,len(tasks[item])):                    
                self.tree_store.append( parent, (tasks[item][x],1) )
    else:
        self.tree_store.append( parent, (tasks[item][0],None) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your tree store to include a boolean that specifies whether the checkbox is to be visible, and connect the `visible` property of the checkbox renderer with the value in the tree store. You can do that by calling `add_attribute`:

```
self.column1.add_attribute( self.renderer1, "visible", 2)
```

...or by adding the keyword argument named like the property to the `gtk.TreeViewColumn` constructor. Here is a small runnable example demonstrating all of the above:

```
import gtk, gobject

tree_store = gtk.TreeStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING,
                           gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                           gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN )
root = tree_store.append(None, ("Computer 1", False, False))
tree_store.append(root, ("C drive", False, True))
tree_store.append(root, ("D drive", True, True))

view = gtk.TreeView(tree_store)
renderer1 = gtk.CellRendererText()
renderer2 = gtk.CellRendererToggle()

view.append_column(gtk.TreeViewColumn("Computer Name",
                                      renderer1, text=0))
view.append_column(gtk.TreeViewColumn("Select Drive",
                                      renderer2, active=1, visible=2))
w = gtk.Window()
w.add(view)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: In above picture I am not able to restrict parent column editable. i want only database child column should be editable other not editable. Plz let me know what i do. i have tried some solution but that is not working. plz help me.

Comment: @Amit Sorry, I do not understand what doesn't work for you. Maybe you should ask a separate question about this new problem?

Comment: Thanks, can you see my new post and let me give solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088336/how-to-make-column-editable-for-perticular-child-in-pygtk